# Pandas DataFrame.sort_values() new method to exclude by row name

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I was working on new function with Pandas DataFrame. It's meant to sort values by column name but exclude specific rows from sorting and return sorted dataframe with that has rows with preserved positions.

E.g. I have a DataFrame

```
       Name     marks
rank1   Tom     10
rank2   Jack    30
rank3   nick    50
rank4   juli    5
```

So I created a function (not finalized, but the idea)

```py
def sort_df_values(df, column_names, ascending=False, fixed_categories=None):
    if fixed_categories is not None and fixed_categories:
        original_positions = {name: position for position, name in enumerate(df.index.values) if name in fixed_categories}
        original_positions = dict(sorted(original_positions.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
    
        excluded = df.loc[fixed_categories]
        included = [name for name in list(df.index) if name not in fixed_categories]
        new_df = df.loc[included].sort_values(column_names, ascending=ascending)
        result = pd.concat([new_df, excluded])

        new_index_values = list(result.index.values)

        while original_positions:
            val, old_position = original_positions.popitem()
            print(val, old_position)
            for current_position, name in enumerate(new_index_values):
                if name == val:
                    new_index_values.insert(old_position, new_index_values.pop(current_position))
                    break
        result = result.reindex(new_index_values)
    else:
        result = df.sort_values(column_names, ascending=ascending)

    return result
```

And then I call it like this:

```py
sort_df_values(df, ['marks'], fixed_categories=['rank3'])
```

The result is correct, I sort all data, but I preserve the excluded rows positions:

```
       Name     marks
rank2   Jack    30
rank1   Tom     10
rank3   nick    50
rank4   juli    5
```

Is there any better option on how to do this? Maybe there is already some feature in pandas that could help me out on this one?

DataFrame example:

```py
{'Name': {'rank1': 'Tom', 'rank2': 'Jack', 'rank3': 'nick', 'rank4': 'juli'},
 'marks': {'rank1': 10, 'rank2': 30, 'rank3': 50, 'rank4': 5}}
```

Comment: Can you share the data in a more convenient format?

Comment: @AMC added example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `pandas` leverage on functions in API almost every function is vectorized.

You can break down your problem into categories.

- If `fixed` is `None` just sort w.r.t given `column_names`.
- Else sort w.r.t given `column_names` but filter filter `fixed` indices.
- insert `fixed` at previous positions.

```
def sort_values(df, column_names, ascending=False, fixed=None):
    if fixed is None:
        return df.sort_values(column_names, ascending=ascending)
    idx = df.index.get_indexer(fixed).tolist()
    s_df = df.sort_values(column_names, ascending=ascending).T
    keep_cols = s_df.columns.difference(fixed, sort=False)
    out = s_df[keep_cols]
    for (loc, name) in zip(idx, fixed):
        out.insert(loc, name, s_df[name])
    return out.T
```

**Note:** `fixed` should be a `list`.

#### Example runs:

```
fixed = ['rank3']
sort_values(df, ['marks'], ascending=False, fixed=fixed)

#        Name marks
# rank2  Jack    30
# rank1   Tom    10
# rank3  nick    50  # rank3 position fixed.
# rank4  juli     5

fixed = ['rank2', 'rank3']
sort_values(df, ['marks'], ascending=True, fixed=fixed) # ascending order.

# sorted in ascending order
#        Name marks
# rank4  juli     5
# rank2  Jack    30 # rank2 position fixed
# rank3  nick    50 # rank3 position fixed
# rank1   Tom    10
```

#### Code Review

- #### `PEP-8` Violations

  - `E501` - Lines longer than 79 characters. You have many lines with length greater than 79 characters.

```
# Examples
original_positions = {name: position for position, name in enumerate(df.index.values) if name in fixed_categories}
# Can be refactored as below 
original_positions = {
    name: position
    for position, name in enumerate(df.index.values)
    if name in fixed_categories
}

original_positions = dict(sorted(original_positions.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
# Can be refactored as below
original_positions = dict(
    sorted(
        original_positions.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True
    )
)
```

---

You can use [pep8online](http://pep8online.com/)<sup>*</sup> to check if your code is in accordance with PEP-8 standard.

You can use [**`black`**](https://pypi.org/project/black/)<sup>*</sup> (code formatting tool)

```
black --line-length 79 your_file.py
```

---

<sub><sub>* I'm not affiliated to `pep8online` and `black`.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thanks very much for the good idea that is sound good what I was looking for. Regarding pep8, I know, this was just a dummy code :) But thanks for the note!